# View Controller turning up black even though there is content

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

So when I click on a button from another View Controller, it is suppose to present the next View Controller. However, when clicking the button, it just show the next View Controller with a black screen, even though there is content on it. How do I fix this?

I do know that there had already been similar questions asked but none helped me in solving this issue.

Button clicked code:

```
@IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {
    presentDetail(SignUpViewController())
}
```

Present next View Controller and animation code:

```
   extension UIViewController {


        func presentDetail(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController) {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.25
            transition.type = CATransitionType.push
            transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
            self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

            self.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: false)
        }

        func dismissDetail() {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.25
            transition.type = CATransitionType.push
            transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
            self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

            dismiss(animated: false)
        }



}
```

To clarify, the presentDetail function suppose to present the next View Controller with an animation (From Right), as shown in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the target ViewController from Storyboard before presenting it.

```
@IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {

presentDetail(

storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "putyourIdentifierhere"))
}
```

instantiateViewController function returns the Viewcontroller you want to present.

Comment: Doing that results in a black screen still. I put the above code right before presentDetail.  And the Storyboard ID is put instead of "putyourIdentifierhere"

Comment: Updated my answer. Does your code look like this. Please update your question.